# Laravel 5.7 restrict accessing the certain page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view file named "register" and I'm using AJAX to validate form. This view page is a modal window containing register form. If type url like "http://localhost/register" it will proceed to the register view. I'm new in laravel and I can not understand how to prevent from accessing this view. Please, help :(

register.blade.php file:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="register">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <p>Sign up</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-reg" style="display:none"></div>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                @csrf

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-md-5 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" autofocus>

                        @if ($errors->has('name'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="email" class="col-md-5 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="password" class="col-md-5 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password">

                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-5 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary regist">
                            {{ __('Register') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

register.blade.php is included in welcome.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('public/css/css.css') }}" />
        <script src="{{ url("public/js/register.js") }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url("public/js/login.js") }}"></script>
        <title>Harry Potter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Harry Potter</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Info<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/">Info</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="/">Info</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    @include('layouts.app')
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="{{ url("public/img/join.jpg") }}" alt="" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Chat and share with other fans!</h2>
                        <p><a href="{{ url("/entrance") }}">Get started!</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="{{ url("public/img/xmashp.png") }}" alt="" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Choose your side!</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="{{ url("public/img/order.jpg") }}" alt="" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Join to the Order of the Phoenix!</h2>
                        <p><a href="#">Learn more!</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="{{ url("public/img/voldemort.jpg") }}" alt="" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h2>Join to the Death Eaters!</h2>
                        <p><a href="#">Learn more!</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        @include('auth.login')
        @include('auth.register')
    </body>
</html>
```

web.php file:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/welcome', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@store');

Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@signIn');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@authenticated');
```

Comment: Do you want only logged in people to access this view? Your question is a little unclear. Please try elaborating and add some of your code and attempts.

Comment: i want to restrict everyone from accesing /register page

Comment: Are you on Laravel 5.7?

Comment: yes, does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP's request:

> I want to restrict everyone from accessing the `/register` page.

There's a few ways you can do this:

- Don't register the routes
- Override the `showRegistrationForm()` function

---

**1 - Don't register the routes (easiest and best solution)**

---

You're using `Auth::routes();` to register your auth related routes, change it to this:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

This won't register the `/register` route and make the page not accessible.

**2 - Override the `showRegistrationForm()` function**

---

Make your way over to: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php`

```
/**
  * Show the application registration form.
  *
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
  public function showRegistrationForm()
  {
     return view('auth.login'); // this changed

     // you can also use this to return with a message
     // return view('auth.login')->with('error', 'Registration disabled.');
  }
```

The big downside of this solution is that it will get overwritten when Laravel updates so I suggest you use the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I'll use the first one it's the best and the easiest way as you said :) You saved my life!

Comment: No problem, glad to help ;)